# is it better to grouping add() function in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I learning java swing, and I'm a little confused with location of add() function

Style 1:

```
    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    add(b1);
    JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    add(b2);
    JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    add(b3);
    JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    add(b4);
    JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
    add(b5);
```

Style 2:

```
    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("5");

    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);
    add(b4);
    add(b5);
```

I usually grouping add() function like style 2, But i'm worried that it's not recommended.

Is there any recommended style? or both is acceptable style?

Comment: It's a matter of personal opinion, I prefer to, where possible, to seperate the initialisation and layout phases, as they can, individually, be complicated and I find it easier to understand what's going on when they are seperated

Comment: The code smells either way. Consider using a loop and/or array (or list).

Comment: @shmosel What if they weren't all buttons, but a combination of other components - I think the type of component is probably irrelevant to the overall question at this point - but you're not wrong ;)

Comment: Thank you! There was a lot of help.